# What exactly do this function declared into functions.php file of a WordPress theme?

Tags: php, content-management-system, wordpress-theming, wordpress

someone can help me to understand what exactly do this function declared into the **functions.php** file of a theme?

```
function exclude_featured_tag( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 'tag__not_in', 'array(ID OF THE FEATURED TAG)' );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'exclude_featured_tag' );
```

I am not into PHP but looking it I think that if the user is on the home page it modifya query object exluding the posts having a specific tag. Is it right?

If it's right can you explain me the last line:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'exclude_featured_tag' );
```

I think that it is used to automatically call the previous function what a specific event happen...is it right? what event? can you help me to understand how exactly work?

Tnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct on both accounts.

Comment: Ok...but can you explain me when this function is automatically called. For what event?

Comment: "This hook is called after the query variable object is created, but before the actual query is run." Taken directly from Wordpress docs [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts). You can get a full list of Wordpress actions [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference)